# Showing the dynamic Images using .NET Cookies code

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, cookies

I am using jQuery and C# to display the slide Images on the page. JQuery comes when all the images are loaded from C# code.

I have got below three images on the page which are generated dynamically using c#.

```
<img id="image1" title="Enjoy a refreshing shower at 43,000 feet" alt="Enjoy a refreshing shower at 43,000 feet" src="/english/images/spa.jpg" style="display: block;">

<img id="image2"  title="The comfort of your own Private Suite" alt="The comfort of your own Private Suite" src="/english/images/suites.jpg" style="display: block;">

<img id="image3"  title="Socialize, relax, and indulge" alt="Socialize, relax, and indulge" src="/english/images/lounge.jpg" style="display: block;">
```

Now I want to write C# code, which will read above images and will store them in cookies. And according to the cookies value the images will be shown.

So if I have seen the first Image, then on next visit of the page, it will show the second image and so on. And after the last images shown, it will start showing first. Basically I am looking to implement below logic.

```
"Each image will show in order and a cookie will maintain which image should be shown next. But the image should not change when the user logs in. Also the cookie will be cleared in case any one of the images are changed."
```

Please guide me how to start, and would appreciate if I can have some sample code

Thanks!

**.NET CODE FOR GENERATING THE IMAGE AND INPUT HIDDEN:**

```
protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {

            // Always start with a clean form
            Controls.Clear();

            //Declaring the List for image list
            List<string> imageList = new List<string>();

            //Declaring the Collection object to add the image list
            NameValueCollection cookiecollection = new NameValueCollection();           

            int cntShow = 0;
            //Adding DIV4 for prev and next
            Panel div4 = new Panel();
            //Adding Input Hidden to get all the values from control
            HtmlGenericControl inputHidden = new HtmlGenericControl("input");
            foreach (FeaturedPromo promo in base.FeaturedPromos)
            {
                inputHidden = new HtmlGenericControl("input");
                inputHidden.Attributes["id"] = promo.ID + "Image";
                inputHidden.Attributes["type"] = "hidden";
                inputHidden.Attributes["src"] = promo.ImageSource;
                inputHidden.Attributes["alt"] = promo.ImageAlt;
                inputHidden.Attributes["title"] = promo.ImageTitle;
                inputHidden.Attributes["href"] = promo.ImageHref;
                inputHidden.Attributes["height"] = promo.ImageHeight;
                inputHidden.Attributes["width"] = promo.ImageWidth;
                inputHidden.Attributes["header"] = promo.ImageHeader;
                inputHidden.Attributes["subheader"] = promo.ImageSubHeader;
                inputHidden.Attributes["color"] = promo.ImageColor;

                this.Controls.Add(inputHidden);

                imageList.Add(promo.ID + "Image");

                if (cntShow == 0)
                {
                    //Add specific div for Featured Promo
                    Panel div1 = new Panel();
                    div1.Attributes["id"] = promo.ID;

                    if (cntShow == 0)
                    {
                        div1.Style["display"] = "block";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        div1.Style["display"] = "none";
                    }

                    //Adding an Image
                    HtmlGenericControl image = new HtmlGenericControl("image");      
                    image.Attributes["src"] = promo.ImageSource;
                    image.Attributes["alt"] = promo.ImageAlt;
                    image.Attributes["title"] = promo.ImageTitle;

                    div1.Controls.Add(image);

                    //Adding two HREF for navigation
                    HtmlGenericControl alinkLeft = new HtmlGenericControl("a");
                    alinkLeft.Attributes["class"] = "slideshow-control-left";
                    alinkLeft.Attributes["href"] = "javascript:void(0);";
                    alinkLeft.Style["display"] = "inline";
                    div1.Controls.Add(alinkLeft);

                    HtmlGenericControl alinkRight = new HtmlGenericControl("a");
                    alinkRight.Attributes["class"] = "slideshow-control-right";
                    alinkRight.Attributes["href"] = "javascript:void(0);";
                    alinkRight.Style["display"] = "inline";
                    div1.Controls.Add(alinkRight);

                    //Adding Second div
                    Panel div2 = new Panel();
                    div2.CssClass = "slideshow-b";
                    div1.Controls.Add(div2);

                    //Adding Third div
                    Panel div3 = new Panel();
                    div3.CssClass = "slideshow-bl";
                    div2.Controls.Add(div3);

                    //Adding the A HREF Link
                    HtmlGenericControl alink = new HtmlGenericControl("a");
                    alink.Attributes["class"] = "slideshow-link";
                    alink.Attributes["href"] = promo.ImageHref;
                    div3.Controls.Add(alink);

                    //Adding the first span                
                    HtmlGenericControl span1 = new HtmlGenericControl("span");
                    span1.Attributes["class"] = "slideshow-header";
                    span1.InnerHtml = promo.ImageHeader;
                    alink.Controls.Add(span1);

                    //Adding line break
                    alink.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br/>"));

                    //Adding the second span
                    HtmlGenericControl span2 = new HtmlGenericControl("span");
                    span2.Attributes["class"] = "slideshow-subheader";
                    span2.InnerHtml = promo.ImageSubHeader;
                    alink.Controls.Add(span2);
                    this.Controls.Add(div1);

                    if (base.FeaturedPromos.Count > 1)
                    {
                        //Adding DIV4 for prev and next
                        div4 = new Panel();
                        div4.CssClass = "slideshow-br";

                        //Adding DIV5 inside DIV4
                        Panel div5 = new Panel();
                        div5.CssClass = "slideshow-br-controls";
                        div4.Controls.Add(div5);

                        //Adding the PREV A HREF Link
                        HtmlGenericControl alinkPrev = new HtmlGenericControl("a");
                        alinkPrev.Attributes["class"] = "slideshow-br-controls-left";
                        alinkPrev.Attributes["href"] = "javascript:void(0);";
                        alinkPrev.Attributes["title"] = "Prev";
                        alinkPrev.Style["display"] = "inline";
                        alinkPrev.Attributes["CurrentDivID"] = promo.ID;
                        div5.Controls.Add(alinkPrev);

                        //Adding the span for prev and next buttons
                        HtmlGenericControl span3 = new HtmlGenericControl("span");
                        span3.Attributes["class"] = "slideshow-br-control-buttons";
                        int count = 0;
                        foreach (FeaturedPromo allPromo in base.FeaturedPromos)
                        {
                            if (count == 0)
                            {
                                //Adding the All HREF Link for Prev and Next
                                HtmlGenericControl aLLlinks = new HtmlGenericControl("a");
                                aLLlinks.Attributes["class"] = "" + count + "-banner-button";
                                aLLlinks.Attributes["href"] = "javascript:void(0);";
                                aLLlinks.Attributes["title"] = allPromo.ImageTitle;
                                aLLlinks.Style["display"] = "inline";

                                //aLLlinks.Attributes["id"] = "active-banner-slide";

                                span3.Controls.Add(aLLlinks);
                                count++;
                            }
                        }

                        div5.Controls.Add(span3);

                        //Adding the NEXT A HREF Link
                        HtmlGenericControl alinkNext = new HtmlGenericControl("a");
                        alinkNext.Attributes["class"] = "slideshow-br-controls-right";
                        alinkNext.Attributes["href"] = "javascript:void(0);";
                        alinkNext.Attributes["title"] = "Next";
                        alinkNext.Style["display"] = "inline";
                        alinkNext.Attributes["CurrentDivID"] = promo.ID;
                        div5.Controls.Add(alinkNext);
                        //div2.Controls.Add(div4);
                    }
                    this.Controls.Add(div1);
                    //this.Controls.Add(div4);
                    cntShow++;
                }
            }
            this.Controls.Add(div4);

            HttpCookie cookielist = new HttpCookie("ImageListOfCookies");

            for (int i = 0; i < imageList.Count; i++)
            {
                cookiecollection.Add("Image_" + i, imageList[i]);                
            }
            cookielist.Values.Add(cookiecollection);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookielist);


        }
```

Comment: Possibly realted to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4874041/how-to-show-the-images-on-the-basis-of-cookies-using-c

Comment: Yes but the answers were not useful for me!

Comment: ok after reading your code and question again this is i think what you want.. you are loading all the images at once to the browser then user starts seeing images if he leave seeing images in between then on next visit you will only show images that were not shown in previous visit. Is this what you want.. please clarify then i will answer

Comment: Yes correct this what I am looking, my .NET code shows the first image in default and creates input hidden fields with the image details, and then JQuery reads all the details from input hidden and convert it into JSON object, which is being passed to JQuery function and then it starts showing images on the click of "Prev" and "Next".

Comment: in that case Zack answer is good...combines with my answer. Here is the logic...As user keeps seeing images append them in the cookie(as told by @Zack)then on next visit check cookie(as told in my answer) and only send those images which are not in the cookie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to accomplish it with Cookies then since you are yourself showing the images in the first place so you know which images are going to be shown, so instead of storing Link to images (which can be pretty long) do this:

- Assign each image an ID like `1` for `spa.jpg` , `2` for `suites.jpg` or more better if the file names are always unique then let the file names be the ID.
- Then just when you show the image append the ID's in cookies like this (I have used | to facilitate splitting and reducing the cookies count to just One).

.

```
//For example to store "spa" if spa image has been stored
 if(Response.Cookies["Shown_Images"] != null)
 {
   Response.Cookies["Shown_Images"].Value = Response.Cookies["Shown_Images"] + "|spa";
 }
else
{
   Response.Cookies["Shown_Images"].Value = "spa";
}
```

Then to retrive if `spa.jpg`has been shown or not

```
if(Response.Cookies["Shown_Images"] != null)
{
   string[] images_shown = Response.Cookies["Shown_Images"];
   if(images_shown.Contains("spa"))
   {
       //If True then do processing;
   }
   else
   {
       //False then do as required
   }
}
```

Comment: @Thanks Shekhar for looking this question, in the last question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918886/how-to-add-remove-replace-list-in-cookies-using-c where you replied for adding the namevaluecollection in cookies will work for above logic or I need to change it, however there is some errors in the code, its giving error I have updated my comments in that question.

Comment: @MKS in this answer i have suggested different approach as now i know your use case...

Comment: @MKS to make the cookie available to jQuery use need to set Response.Cookie["Shown_Images"].HttpOnly = true;

Comment: @Shekhar, It is possible to this using .NET or I have to go with some client side like @ZACk has suggested

Comment: @MKS @zack has givven a good answer..but i suggest u leave the jQuery only for animation etc.. from the server just only show those images which have not been shown yet and let jQuery do any client side woork...

Comment: Thanks Shekhar, so in your last answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918886/how-to-add-remove-replace-list-in-cookies-using-c, we are creating the cookies with the collection of images to be shown, so now what code will be written for "Shown_Image" cookies and what will be JQuery doing.

Comment: @Shekhar, please suggest to my problem, if you get time, its really a headache to me :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this client side with jQuery, you can use the cookies plugin to read/write cookies.  Here is a example that will set the first image to display by default, then create a cookie with 2 values (LastDisplayed, Size) to figure out what image to display next.

Scripts Used

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.cookie.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/json2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Styles Used

```
<style type="text/css">
    .hide
    {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```

JavaScript Used (Using [jQuery's Cookie Plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/raw/master/jquery.cookie.js) and [JSON.org's JSON2](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/raw/master/json2.js)).

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Add class to hide all the images
        $('img').addClass('hide');

        // Get the cookie to figure out the last image displayed
        var cookieval = $.cookie('the_cookie');


        if (cookieval != null) {
            // Parese cookie value into object
            var obj = JSON.parse(cookieval);

            // Check if last displayed is less than the total
            if (obj.LastDisplayed < obj.Size) {
                // Increment Count
                obj.LastDisplayed++;
                // Show next image
                $('img:eq(' + obj.LastDisplayed + ')').removeClass('hide');
            } else {
                // Reset last displayed to 0
                obj.LastDisplayed = 0;
                // Show first image
                $('img:eq(0)').removeClass('hide');
            }

            // Update Cookie
            $.cookie('the_cookie', JSON.stringify(obj));
        } else {
            // Show first image
            $('img :eq(0)').removeClass('hide');
            // Create object to store last displayed and total available
            var obj = {};
            obj.LastDisplayed = 0;
            obj.Size = $('img').length - 1;

            // Create the cookie
            $.cookie('the_cookie', JSON.stringify(obj));
        }
    });
```

Comment: @Thanks Zack, how can I create a cookie with 2 values (LastDisplayed, Size), my current cookies which has got the collection of all the images to be shown, so my cookies is something like this, the name of cookie is "ImageListOfCookies" and its values are  "Image_0=image1&Image_1=image2&Image_2=image3", please suggest

Comment: What your seeing is a standard .NET cookie, you could create a .NET cookie that has the 2 values by doing something like this...   HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("Settings");  cookie["LastDisplayed"] = XXX;  cookie["Size"] = XXX; Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);  If you want to use this with the JavaScript above, you'll probably need to split the cookie results into key/value pairs.  Use Firebug to see the what $.cookie() returns.

Comment: Guys I am just confused how I am going to know which Image was shown the last load, do I need to do it with .NET or JQuery, Please see me .NET code which is generating Dynamic HTML and input Hidden to pass JSON object to JQuery to show the prev and next images on the click. I am going to post my .NET code above, please let me know if JQuery code is required, Shekhar can you please suggest for .NET code.