# How to add/remove/replace LIST in cookies using C#

Tags: c#, cookies

How can add/remove/replace LIST in cookies using C#.

```
//Declaring the List for image list

List<string> imageList = new List<string>();
foreach (FeaturedPromo promo in base.FeaturedPromos)
{
    imageList.Add(promo.ImageHref);
}
```

In above code, I have got a list with all the Image HREF values in it, Now I want to add these values in cookies using C#, after that I can remove that item from cookies and also replace the value with other value of same item in cookies.

Please suggest!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cookies are not removed they are just overwritten or expired (sometimes forced to expire).

To add it to cookies just create a Cookie  Name Value collection and add each item from list to the Collection.

Example to add a list of items to cookies:

```
System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection cookiecoll = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();
for(int i = 0 ; i < imageList.Length; i++)
{
    cookiecoll.Add("item_" + i,imageList[i] );
}

HttpCookie cookielist = new HttpCookie("MyListOfCookies");
cookielist.Values.Add(cookiecoll);
Response.Cookies.Add(cookielist);
```

Example To Edit "item_2"

```
 Response.Cookies["MyListofCookies"].Values["item_3"] = "new value";
```

Example to delete  cookies:

```
Response.Cookies["MyListOfCookies"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
```

Example to delete a single item from list (just overwrite with nothing )

```
Response.Cookies["MyListOfCookies"].Values["item_3"] = String.Empty;
```

---

Note: But remember you can't add too much data in cookies.. many browsers have a upper limit to the size and number of cookies you can store.

Comment: @Thanks Shekhar, can I have some example code or links in which I can see how to add,remove LIST in cookies and then further I can change the value in cookies

Comment: @MKS i have updated my answer... to refresh you still need to overwrite the values.. to delete a single value in item just Edit the item to String.Empty;

Comment: Thanks Shekhar, now your above code is just adding/editing and deleting values in cookies, I am looking little more and would require your help/suggestion, after adding these values in cookies, How can I refresh the cookie if any value in ImageList has been changed. I mean if Image HREF get changed, I want to refresh the cookies and will add the new values in it. Can you please look to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918367/showing-the-dynamic-images-using-net-cookies-code

Comment: Well Thanks Shekhar for your help in this question, in your above code while adding to collection to cookies values we need to use "cookielist.Values.Add(cookiecoll);" instead of "cookielist.Values = cookiecoll;"

Comment: @MKS yeah sorry nasty mistake .. forgot that Values is a Readonly property..just corrected that...

Answer (score 0):

you could use

```
// Add cookie
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("MyCookieBizkit", imageList));

// Remove cookie
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Remove("MyCookieBizkit");

// Edit
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["MyCookieBizkit"] = imageList;

// Get
imageList = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["MyCookieBizkit"] != null ? (List<string>)HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["MyCookieBizkit"] : new List<string>();
```

Comment: How to modify the particular one value in LIST, do I need to user NameValueCollection, please suggest

Comment: once you get the value from the Cookie, you can cast it to its original object then you're back to normal.  All cookies are stored in NameValueCollection object.

Comment: @Thanks, can I have some example code using above code, its really new for me

Comment: in your example, you are adding a List of strings to the cookie, you simply cannot change a particular value on that List, whatever object you save to the cookie, once you retrieve it, it is still the same object as long as the object is serializable.

Comment: you could use NameValueCollection or the actual `FeaturedPromo` it self but I don't advice it.

Comment: yeah Shekhar has given good example to adding/editing/deleting the values in cookies, however how can I check current cookie if any values in ImageList has been modified